# Joining array of objects using liquid template language

Tags: json, xml, liquid

I'm building a liquid template to help convert some XML to JSON.

Sample XML input:

```
<ticket>
  <account-id type="integer">123456</account-id>
  <cc-email>
     <cc-emails type="array">
       <cc-email>abc@email.com</cc-email>
       <cc-email>xyz@email.com</cc-email>
     </cc-emails>
     <fwd-emails type="array">
       <fwd-email>abc@email.com</fwd-email>
       <fwd-email>xyz@email.com</fwd-email>
     </fwd-emails>
  </cc-email>
</ticket>
```

Desired JSON output:

```
{
  "account-id":"123456",
  "cc-email":"abc@email.com,xyz@email.com",
  "fwd-email":"abc@email.com,xyz@email.com"
}
```

Liquid template attempt 1:

```
{
    "account-id":"{{ ticket.account-id }}",

    {% assign list = '' | split: ',' %}
    {% for item in ticket.cc-email.cc-emails %}
        {% assign list = list | push: item %}
    {% endfor %}
    "cc-email":"{{ list | join: ',' }}",

    {% assign list = '' | split: ',' %}
    {% for item in ticket.cc-email.fwd-emails %}
        {% assign list = list | push: item %}
    {% endfor %}
    "fwd-email":"{{ list | join: ',' }}"
}
```

Liquid template attempt 2:

```
{
    "account-id":"{{ ticket.account-id }}",

    {% assign list = '' | split: ',' %}
    {% for item in ticket.cc-email.cc-emails %}
        {% assign list = list | push: item.cc-email %}
    {% endfor %}
    "cc-email":"{{ list | join: ',' }}",

    {% assign list = '' | split: ',' %}
    {% for item in ticket.cc-email.fwd-emails %}
        {% assign list = list | push: item.fwd-email %}
    {% endfor %}
    "fwd-email":"{{ list | join: ',' }}"
}
```

I've also tried appending the items to a string. No matter the method, I only get the following output:

```
{
  "account-id":"123456",
  "cc-email":"",
  "fwd-email":""
}
```

Can anyone help point out the issue? Seems like it has to be something simple but I haven't been able to find it.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going back to appending strings. Got this to work:

```
    {% assign cc-email-list = '' %}
    {% for item in ticket.cc-email.cc-emails %}
       {% assign cc-email-list = cc-email-list | Append: item %}
       {% if forloop.last == false %}
          {% assign cc-email-list = cc-email-list | Append: ',' %}
       {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    "cc-email":"{{ cc-email-list }}",
```

Comment: hi, what about the objects? did you append strings only in the end?